# Who is Raksha Kali?

Tags: identification-request, tantra, goddess

I Recently have heard about Goddess Raksha Kali and I want to know about this goddess. My question are:-

- Who is Raksha Kali and Is any mention/stories about This goddess in tantras or any scriptures?
- She is the form of Kali or she herself is Kali?

Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know where exactly in scripture is Raksha-Kali mentioned. The answer to the second question is Raksha-Kali is Kali.

I have posted below a conversation between the Brahmo leader Sri Keshab Chandra Sen and Sri Ramakrishna.

> KESHAB (with a smile): "Describe to us, sir, in how many ways Kali,
> the Divine Mother, sports in this world."
>
> MASTER (with a smile): "Oh, She plays in different ways. It is She
> alone who is known as Maha-Kali, Nitya-Kali, Smasana-Kali,
> **Raksha-Kali**, and Syama-Kali. Maha-Kali and Nitya-Kali are mentioned in
> the Tantra philosophy. When there were neither the creation, nor the
> sun, the moon, the planets, and the earth, and when darkness was
> enveloped in darkness, then the Mother, the Formless One, Maha-Kali,
> the Great Power, was one with Maha-Kala, the Absolute.
>
> "Syama-Kali has a somewhat tender aspect and is worshipped in the
> Hindu households. She is the Dispenser of boons and the Dispeller of
> fear. **People worship Raksha-Kali, the Protectress, in times of
> epidemic, famine, earthquake, drought, and flood.** Smasana-Kali is the
> embodiment of the power of destruction. She resides in the cremation
> ground, surrounded by corpses, jackals, and terrible female spirits.
> From Her mouth flows a stream of blood, from Her neck hangs a garland
> of human heads, and around Her waist is a girdle made of human hands.
>
> "After the destruction of the universe, at the end of a great cycle,
> the Divine Mother garners the seeds for the next creation: She is like
> the elderly mistress of the house, who has a hotchpotch-pot in which
> she keeps different articles for household use. (All laugh.)
>
> "Oh, yes! Housewives have pots like that, where they keep 'sea-foam',
> (The Master perhaps referred to the cuttlefish bone found on the
> seashore. The popular belief is that it is hardened sea-foam.) blue
> pills, small bundles of seeds of cucumber, pumpkin, and gourd, and so
> on. They take them out when they want them. In the same way, after the
> destruction of the universe, my Divine Mother, the Embodiment of
> Brahman, gathers together the seeds for the next creation. After the
> creation the Primal Power dwells in the universe itself. She brings
> forth this phenomenal world and then pervades it. In the Vedas
> creation is likened to the spider and its web. The spider brings the
> web out of itself and then remains in it. God is the container of the
> universe and also what is contained in it.
>
> "Is Kali, my Divine Mother, of a black complexion? She appears black
> because She is viewed from a distance; but when intimately known She
> is no longer so. The sky appears blue at a distance; but look at it
> close by and you will find that it has no colour. The water of the
> ocean looks blue at a distance, but when you go near and take it in
> your hand, you find that it is colourless."

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 5**

Comment: Thx for posting this info ! :) Good stuff. Lots of different forms of Maa Kali in different religious texts. As a brand new Shakta convert I love to learn abt them and understand more :D

Comment: Thank you devi bhakt for your comment. Read The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna to learn about a great devi bhakta.